# iOS Facebook SDK - Error code 8

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.x

The Facebook SDK for iOS worked great until now. Since 2 hours ago, I'm constantly receiving the following error message when I'm trying to log in with Facebook:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={NSRecoveryAttempter=<_FBSDKTemporaryErrorRecoveryAttempter: 0x7fb060edae20>, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=2, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Momentan serverul este ocupat. Te rugăm să încerci din nou., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=500, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=1, NSLocalizedRecoveryOptions=<CFArray 0x7fb0638b71b0 [0x10c2fea40]>{type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
    0 : OK
)}, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 2;
            "fbtrace_id" = Et3O2yEtpV7;
            "is_transient" = 1;
            message = "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 500;
}}
```

I **have** verified:

1. The bundle ID is correct
2. The parameters are correct - id,email,name,gender,birthday,picture.width(1080).height(1080),bio,location,friends
3. The SDK is correctly installed (info.plist with all the requirements - fb{app-id} etc)
4. All the methods inside the AppDelegate are added and are correctly updated for iOS 9

What should I do? I have tested the SDK on another app and there it's working.